# Как прописать nginx правила только для конкретного location?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, сервер, site

Если конфиг nginx такой, то все работает, захожу по адресу example.com перекидывает на example.com/warehouse/index.php?q=p:7

файлы php сайта находятся в папке /var/www/warehouse

конфиги nginx пока минимальные т.к. планируются несколько сайтов с соответствующими location

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www;
index index.php index.html;
server_name example.com;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location = / {
    rewrite ^.+ /warehouse/index.php permanent;
}

location ~ /warehouse/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /warehouse/index.php;
}
}
```

Если конфиг nginx такой

```
server {
listen 80;
root /var/www;
index index.php index.html;
server_name _;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location /warehouse/ {
    rewrite ^.+ /warehouse/index.php permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /warehouse/index.php;
}
}
```

то при попытке захода по адресу example.com/warehouse перекидывает на example.com/?q=p:7 и соотвественно не работает

Вопрос в следующем как конкретно прописать правила только для location ~ /warehouse/ чтобы nginx понимал если заходят по адресу example.com/warehouse надо перекинуть на example.com/warehouse/index.php

Comment: Хранить сайт в /var/www/ - плохая практика. А какой пользователь имеет туда доступ?

Comment: @Piterden хранить систему в `/` тоже плохая практика? А конфиги в `/etc`?

Comment: @Piterden по умолчанию www-data, так же сделал 
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` 

`sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www`

Comment: Напиши в конфиге `location = /warehouse  { return 302 /warehouse/index.php; }`

Comment: @norbornen Добавил после 
`location /warehouse/ { rewrite ^.+ /warehouse/index.php permanent; try_files $uri $uri/ /warehouse/index.php;}`
еще попробовал вместо него, но все так же возвращается в example.com/?q=p:3, есть еще идеи?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт а еще называться чужими именами.